# PHP array grouping by ID

Tags: php, adodb

I have an a bunch of rows in an array with Order Numbers and other order data:

```
    Array ( [ORDER] => 257 [DATE] => 2011-06-13 [ITEM] => LOT98 [QTYORDERED] => 10.00 ) 
    Array ( [ORDER] => 258 [DATE] => 2011-06-15 [ITEM] => FF25 [QTYORDERED] => 450.00 ) 
    Array ( [ORDER] => 258 [DATE] => 2011-07-06 [ITEM] => FF25 [QTYORDERED] => 225.00 ) 
    Array ( [ORDER] => 259 [DATE] => 2011-06-08 [ITEM] => A151412 [QTYORDERED] => 90.00) 
    Array ( [ORDER] => 259 [DATE] => 2011-06-15 [ITEM] => A151412 [QTYORDERED] => 402.00 ) 
    Array ( [ORDER] => 259 [DATE] => 2011-07-06 [ITEM] => A151412 [QTYORDERED] => 357.00 )
```

I would like to place those rows into a single array grouped by ORDER No in a style similar to this:

```
    Order ID Date Item QTYOrdered
    257   0  xx   xx   xx
    258   0  xx   xx   xx
          1  xx   xx   xx
    259   0  xx   xx   xx
          1  xx   xx   xx
          2  xx   xx   xx
```

My code so far:

```
    $ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC;
    $RecordSet = $db->Execute("$q2");   
    while ($row = $RecordSet->FetchRow()) {}
```

Comment: so... you want `Order` to be `null` if it is the same as previous or you want to have 2dimensional array?

Comment: I want a two dimensional array. Hakre already answered my question, big props to him :)

Comment: i saw his answer, but thought that you might mean something other =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you while-loop:

```
$ordered[$row['ORDER']][] = $row;
```

after the loop you have that:

```
var_dump($ordered);
```

Automatically packed together based on the order-key.

Comment: So simple, why couldn't I come up with an answer... Thanks :)

Comment: and put ORDER BY ``order`` in your query + create index to that column

Comment: Venimus could you extrapolate on the index part? How would it improve things and how should it be done properly?

Comment: I think he means: If you keep the $row's comming already ordered based on their `ORDER` column and then by (autoincrement?) `ID` you can control the order of data within `$ordered` as well.

Comment: I am not too concerned about their order as long as they are grouped by correct ORDER no. However, that is a possible way to tidy up the final two dimensional array.